# How can I mark multiple location in google map from mysql table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I mark multiple locations in google map. Latitude and Longitute are getting from my table as json response. Please check below code and json response and correct me?
When I `alert(myCenter)` latitude and longitude are showing correctly but not showing correctly on map

**Json encode**

```
[{"id":"1","lat":"9.9710364","lng":"76.2382596","address":"Ernakulam, pra"},{"id":"2","lat":"9.5946677"
,"lng":"76.5030831","address":"Kochi pra"},{"id":"3","lat":"8.8862925","lng":"76.5850831","address":"Kollam
 pra"},{"id":"4","lat":"8.4998965","lng":"76.8543216","address":"Trivandrum pra"}]
```

**Code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
            <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">   
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Load Multiple Marker</h1>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Map -->
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'geo-locations.php',
                        success:function(data){
                            //Loop through each location.
                            $.each(data, function(){
                                //Plot the location as a marker
                                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
//alert(myCenter)
                                function initialize()
                                {
                                    var mapProp = {
                                        center: myCenter,
                                        zoom:5,
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    };

                                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: myCenter,
                                        title:'Click to zoom'
                                    });

                                    marker.setMap(map);

                                    // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
                                        map.setZoom(9);
                                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                                    });
                                }
                                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to initialize map instance per every marker, you could change the flow to:

- initialize a map
- once the data is loaded, place markers on the map

**Example**

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://rawgit.com/vgrem/e2dda2a255a24df92bff/raw/d9c694b635612ee405c7d16c355dca19adb6380c/geo-locations.json',
        success: function (data) {
           initialize(data);
        }
    });
});


function addMarker(map,position){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(9);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
}


function initialize(data) {
    var mapProp = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $.each(data,function(pos) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        addMarker(map,pos);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```html
<h1>Load Multiple Marker</h1>
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

[**PhpFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jqyg-e24n)

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it